# Find first bit, find last bit assembly using bsf, blf

Tags: assembly, kernel, bit-manipulation, x86-64

I'm looking at this code:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/bitops.h

`static inline unsigned long __ffs(unsigned long word)
 {
         asm("rep; bsf %1,%0"
                 : "=r" (word)
                 : "rm" (word));
         return word;
 }`

why is there a "rep" in front of bsf instruction ? And why this is not the case for `__fls` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a hack to turn the `bfs` into `tzcnt` on processors that support it. It sure would have warranted a comment in the code, though. To quote the instruction set reference:

> 0F BC /r BSF r32, r/m32
>
> F3 0F BC /r TZCNT r32, r/m32
>
> TZCNT counts the number of trailing least significant zero bits in
>   source operand (second operand) and returns the result in destination
>   operand (first operand). TZCNT is an extension of the BSF instruction.
>   The key difference between TZCNT and BSF instruction is that TZCNT
>   provides operand size as output when source operand is zero while in
>   the case of BSF instruction, if source operand is zero, the content of
>   destination operand are undefined. On processors that do not support
>   TZCNT, the instruction byte encoding is executed as BSF.

(The `REP` prefix is `F3` of course.)

Comment: is there any performance benefit ? As in the comment, the return value is still undefined if we consider compiling for different platform.

Comment: Yes, for certain cpus there may be a performance benefit. According to Agner Fog's doc, most AMD cpus take 3 or 4 clocks for `BSF` but only 2 for `TZCNT`. On Intel Haswell, they take the same time.