# Does this simple code not containing any loop generate a loop in assembly?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, x86, bit-manipulation

I was playing with this code to check if an integer is a power of 4:

```cpp
// C++ version

bool is_pow_4(unsigned a) {
    return (std::popcount(a) == 1) && (std::countr_zero(a) % 2 == 0);
}
```

```c
// C version

int is_pow_4(unsigned a) {
   return (__builtin_popcount(a) == 1) && (__builtin_ctz(a) % 2 == 0);
}
```

Basically I check that there is just one bit set and it is on an odd position.

I was expecting a branchless code, however I see two jumps and a `rep` instruction. From what I recall a `rep` is basically a loop, but on assembly level. It seems that `std::countr_zero`/`__builtin_ctz` generates the `rep` instruction.

[C++ output](https://godbolt.org/z/Goz153zP9):

```
is_pow_4(unsigned int):
        lea     edx, [rdi-1]
        mov     ecx, edi
        xor     eax, eax
        xor     ecx, edx
        cmp     edx, ecx
        jb      .L7
.L1:
        ret
.L7:
        mov     eax, 1
        test    edi, edi
        je      .L1
        xor     eax, eax
        rep bsf eax, edi
        not     eax
        and     eax, 1
        ret
```

[C output](https://godbolt.org/z/GKdcPr4j3) is similar.

I understand that the loop is bound by the width of the integer (32), so I think the complexity of the code is `O(1)`, but I was still surprised to find a loop.

Is my understanding correct? Is this code a loop on x86? Is this because while there is a x86 popcount instruction, there is no count leading/trailing zeros x86 instruction?

Comment: It looks like you can use `-march=native` option to enable `popcnt` and `tzcnt` instructions and avoid (at least explicit) loops.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

Comment: `rep bsf` is not a loop E: see also [Find first bit, find last bit assembly using bsf, blf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33175375/555045)

Comment: _"I was expecting a branchless code"_ - I think that's going to be tricky if you use `&&` since it  must short-circuit in case the first condition is false.

Comment: @TedLyngmo true. The branchless code is not that important, is not that surprising to me.

Comment: @harold I am missing some context and assembly knowledge. I don't understand "the REP prefix is F3 of course". Isn't `rep` the repeat string instruction?

Comment: @bolov no `rep` by itself doesn't mean anything, it only modifies the action of the instruction that it is attached to, not always by turning it into a loop (but that was its original use)

Comment: `rep bsf` is `tzcnt` written in a way that's compatible with obsolete versions of GAS.  That encoding with a mandatory REP prefix lets it run as `bsf` on old CPUs, as documented: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/tzcnt  The branch is on whether there's a single bit set, like your code asked for, using `blsmsk(x) == x` I think (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blsmsk); without `-march=x86-64-v3` (or `-mbmi`), it uses LEA/XOR.  Two separate things to check as part of an `&&` will normally result in two branches if they don't easily combine into one boolean condition.

Comment: Thank you all. I understand now! Consider writing an answer.

Comment: `rep` only repeats RCX times when used as a prefix to a "string" instruction.  See also [What does "rep; nop;" mean in x86 assembly? Is it the same as the "pause" instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33639300) and [Assembly x86 REP, REPZ, REPNZ, XACQUIRE and XRELEASE instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46487511) re: tzcnt and other cases of `rep` being undefined on paper until documented as being ignored by old CPUs.

Comment: It seems like `rep` is the key misunderstanding here, so it's probably a duplicate of one of those Q&As; writing up an answer for other details of this very specific case are probably unlikely to help other future readers.  Hmm, maybe there's a good duplicate about why GCC chooses `rep bsf` (aka `tzcnt`) for performance after checking for non-zero.  If not, maybe there should be.  [Why does TZCNT work for my Sandy Bridge processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43880227) is related but comes at it from a different angle.

Comment: What happened to the simple: `if ((x & 3) == 0)`?  No branches, no need to repeat, just simple Binary Arithmetic.

Comment: 81 is a 3^4. Why do you check for the 1 bit being set only?

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko This is checking for 4^n not n^4

Comment: return (std::popcount(a) == 1) * (std::countr_zero(a) % 2 == 0);